# How to make a request to website and download search data

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to download some car VIN data for a list of individuals. This involves making a request to a website "http://vin.place/search.php" via requests.get in python3.7.

My code looks like this:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

payload = {'first name':'JOHN','last name':'DOE'}
webpage_response = requests.get("http://vin.place/search.php",data = payload)

webpage = webpage_response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage,"html.parser")

results = soup.select(".search-content")

for x in results:
  print(x.get_text())
```

Unfortunately, I am finding that results = [] instead. I suspect there is something wrong with the way that I am coding up the `requests.get` command. I am not sure how what the right keys should be for the website. Can anyone please help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The payload you have is wrong, it should be `first`, `last`. And the names in lowercase:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

payload = {'first':'john','last':'doe'}
webpage_response = requests.post("http://vin.place/search.php", data=payload)

webpage = webpage_response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage,"html.parser")

results = soup.select(".search-content")

for x in results:
    print(x.text)
```

Prints:

```
JOHN DOE  Purchase of a  2007 HONDA ACCORD
JOHN DOE  Purchase of a  2007 CHRYSLER TOWN AND COUNTRY
JOHN DOE  Purchase of a  2007 DODGE RAM PICKUP 2500
JOHN DOE  Purchase of a  2007 DODGE RAM PICKUP 1500
JOHN DOE  Purchase of a  2007 VOLKSWAGEN PASSAT
JOHN DOE  Purchase of a  2007 VOLKSWAGEN JETTA
JOHN DOE  Purchase of a  2007 CHRYSLER SEBRING
JOHN DOE  Purchase of a  2007 DODGE RAM PICKUP 1500
JOHN DOE  Purchase of a  2007 JEEP PATRIOT
JOHN DOE  Purchase of a  2007 Chevrolet TrailBlazer
JOHN DOE  Purchase of a  2007 FORD EDGE
JOHN DOE  Purchase of a  2007 JEEP WRANGLER UNLIMITED
JOHN DOE  Purchase of a  2007 DODGE RAM PICKUP 2500
JOHN DOE  Purchase of a  2007 FORD MUSTANG
JOHN DOE  Purchase of a  2007 JEEP WRANGLER
JOHN DOE  Purchase of a  2007 CHRYSLER 300
JOHN DOE  Purchase of a  2007 JEEP WRANGLER UNLIMITED
JOHN DOE  Purchase of a  2007 DODGE MAGNUM
JOHN DOE  Purchase of a  2007 CADILLAC ESCALADE ESV
JOHN DOE  Purchase of a  2007 FORD F-150
JOHN DOE  Purchase of a  2007 HONDA ACCORD
JOHN DOE  Purchase of a  2007 JEEP LIBERTY
JOHN DOE  Purchase of a  2007 CADILLAC ESCALADE
JOHN DOE  Purchase of a  2007 DODGE RAM PICKUP 1500
JOHN DOE  Purchase of a  2007 JEEP WRANGLER
```

Comment: OMG this really works. Thanks a million @AndrejKesely

Answer (score 0):

looking at the form data as sent by chrome when performing the search manually, the data is: `first=JOHN&last=DOE`, also, the site uses `POST`

please try this:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

payload = {'first':'JOHN','last':'DOE'}
webpage_response = requests.post("http://vin.place/search.php",data = payload)

webpage = webpage_response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage,"html.parser")

results = soup.select(".search-content")

for x in results:
  print(x.get_text())
```

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right @Adam.Er8 I found this line in the source file <form action="search.php" method="post" class="search-form"> But how did you find out that the data is first=JOHN&last=DOE? All I can tell from the source code is that name = 'first' is the name of the first value and name = 'last' is the name of the second value